# Insert into mysql from linux terminal

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

I have a question. i can insert into mysql database from linux terminal a record with this command:

```
mysql dbTest insert into tablename values(1,"b","c")
```

Now i have a file in Linux with some records
 for example:

```
$cat file

2, "c", "e"
3, "r", "q"
4, "t", "w"
5, "y", "e"
6, "u", "r"
7, "g", "u"
8, "f", "j"
9, "v", "k"
```

i don't know how can i insert all records to the file to mysql database from linux terminal.

I intent with a bash file but i don't know =(

Comment: Look at the MySQL docs for `load data local infile`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing a series of inserts is not the best choice performance-wise. Since your input data exist as CSV you'd be better off doing a [bulk load](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) as @Kevin suggested:

```
mysql dbTest -e "LOAD DATA INFILE './file' INTO TABLE tablename FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom sql file using `sed`.

From a terminal execute the following code:

```
sed 's/\(^[0-9"]*, [a-z"]*, [a-z]*$\)/INSERT INTO tablename VALUES(\1);/g' source_file > sql_script.sql
```

After you can easily use the `source` command to insert the records.

```
$ mysql -u mysqlusername -p -h host
Enter password: your_secret_password

Mysql > use yourdatabasename
Mysql > source sql_script.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk you could use the existing file and insert values from bash itself:

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "mysql -u root -p dbTest << EOF"} {print "insert into tablename values (" $0 ");"} END {print "EOF"}' file |bash -v
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql -e "use databasename;insert into TABLENAME values ('POST',........);"

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Mysql :

   ```
   sudo apt-get install mysql-server
   ```
2. Goto Mysql shell:

   ```
   mysql -u root -p 
          password:******
   ```
3. Show Database( if already exist):

   ```
   show databases;
   ```
4. Create a databases:

   ```
   create database employees;
   ```
5. Access the created database:

   ```
   use employees;</code>
   ```
6. Create a table (Be careful on "``" and " `" : use acute`sign in each field):

   ```
   create table `employees`( `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `first_name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,`last_name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, `email` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, `department` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL, `salary` DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`id`)) 
   ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;
   ```
7. Add Information to a table:

   ```
   INSERT INTO `employees` (`id`,`first_name`,`last_name`,`email`,`department`,`salary`) 
   VALUES (1, 'Sumanta','Silwal','sumantasilwal10@gmail.com','Computer Design', '5000.00');
   ```
8. Look the created tale:

   ```
   select * from employees;
   ```

Note: use "`" sign in each field like employees, id, first_name, last_name, email, department and salary.

**Enjoy coding.